# Can't create new session keyring with keyctl

Tags: linux, key-management

According of a documentation I have to create new session keyring when my script starts.

```
keyctl new_session
```

Sometimes the command returns the new keyring ID but often I get error message:

> keyctl_session_to_parent: Operation not permitted

When it happens the content of keyring:

```
> cat /proc/keys
1c63fa6b I--Q---     2 perm 1f3f0000 50848 65534 keyring   _uid.50848: empty
21291866 I--Q---     1 perm 1f3f0000 50848 65534 keyring   _uid_ses.50848: 1
263af424 I--Q---     4 perm 1f3f0000     0 65534 keyring   _uid.0: empty
30e8b23b I--Q---    11 perm 3f030000     0     0 keyring   _ses: 1
```

Could you advice what happens and how to avoid the error message?
Could it be caused by sudo?

Comment: I wonder if it could be a kernel bug? https://lore.kernel.org/all/20190827191824.259566-1-ebiggers@kernel.org/

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's because of the ownership.
Based on [the man page of the 'keyctl_session_to_parent()'](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/keyctl_session_to_parent.3.html), the calling process (the 'keyctl' command) and the parent process (the current shell) must have same 'UID:GID'.
[image]

Comment: The customer script was triggered by root via su/sudo. That could caused the issue.